# julia: a function object

Tags: function, julia

I want to use an object in Julia, which can be initialized by a function. It's like a function pointer in C.

Here is my goal:

I have a julia script and a julia module.

In this script, I have an array.
The module needs to be able to add some elements into this array.

```
#script
liste = Int64[]
function addElement(e)
   liste.push(e)
end
include("path/mymodule.jl")
myModule.setAddElementFunc(addElement)
myModule.execute() # error: wrong number of parameter



#mymodule.jl

module myModule
export setAddElementFunc
export execute

addElementFunc = ()->()

funciton setAddElementFunc(fn)
   addElementFunc = fn
end

function execute()
   addElementFunc(3)
end

end
```

Basically, my idea is:
in the module, we can't do anything BUT `add`. I need to do such a structure because my job is to code the julia script and some other people will code the module. So I want to limit his right to keep the liste safe, in this case, he can just add elements.

Comment: `global addElementFunc = fn` and also `function execute(arg::Tuple)
   addElementFunc(arg...)
end`

Comment: @RezaAfzalan   Is there any other way except `arg...`. I prefer to use an object like function pointer in C.

Comment: `addElementFunc(arg...) === apply(addElementFunc,arg)`

Comment: @RezaAfzalan   aha, this is a good idea. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although @David is compliantly right, I would like to point out the usefulness of `global` keyword. I like to think of it **here** as an CPP `this` alike keyword in Julia-Lang.

```
module test
  addMsgFunc=()->()
  function getAddMsgFunc(fn)
    global addMsgFunc = fn
  end
  function show()
    println("xxxxx")
  end
end
julia> addMsgFunc
ERROR: UndefVarError: addMsgFunc not defined
julia> test.addMsgFunc();
julia> test.getAddMsgFunc(test.show);
julia> test.addMsgFunc()
xxxxx
julia> addMsgFunc # Its in global but in another scope
ERROR: UndefVarError: addMsgFunc not defined
julia> test.addMsgFunc=()->() # You cant assign to it normally
ERROR: cannot assign variables in other modules
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. There is only one question: if show() has one parameter, how to change `addMsgFunc=()->()`?

Comment: there is no type checking in module level, so do not think of it as an `cpp` class, and `addMsgFunc=()->()` do not work like an initializer ,really you don't need it. I think your question is a sign of misunderstanding.

Comment: Using a global like that is a really bad idea in my opinion. It is "un-Julian" and will be slow. It also makes it very hard to reason about the code, since anybody could modify the global variable from anywhere. Maybe what you are looking for is actually to embed a function inside a user-defined type?

Comment: @David , I'm partly agree with you, please check the latest edit

Comment: plz check my lastest edit. I don't want to use any global variable at all but I don't know how to generate a user-defined type, something like class in cpp. I'm totally a newbie in Julia.

Comment: @DavidP.Sanders   plz check my lastest edit. If I don't use a global variable, what should I do?

Answer (score 3):

To generate a new type in Julia we can do something like

```
type MyArray{T}
    elements::Vector{T}
    my_value::Int
end
```

This automatically makes a couple of default constructors for you.
You can make an object of your type by feeding it the initial values for each of its fields.

```
v = MyArray([3, 5], 17)
```

In Julia, functions do *not* live inside objects, but rather are methods defined outside the objects. In this sense, objects in Julia are similar to structs in C, except that they can (and, usually, should) be parametrised by type, as in this example (the `{T}`).

In this case, for example, you can simply define your own method of the generic function `push!` from base Julia, to act on objects of your new type:

```
push!(x::MyArray, value) = push!(x.elements, value)
```

Now you can do

```
push!(v, 4)
```

to add the value 4 to your object.

You should read the Julia manual and have a look at some tutorials for more information on defining types. Let us know if anything is not clear.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got you. I've read some tutorials but I still don't know how to declare a function object, something like function pointer in C.

Comment: For now, I do like this: in the module, `function execute(fn1, fn2)`; In the script, I can call `myModule.execute(addElement, setElement)`, `addElement` and `setElement` are two functions in the script. It works. So I don't need any function pointer anymore. If you know how to declare a function pointer in Julia, tell me :D    thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It is not completely clear what you want to do.
One possibility is the following:

```
function getAddMsgFunc(fn)
  fn  # just return the function that is passed in
end

function my_show()
  println("xxxxx")
end

addMsgFunc = getAddMsgFunc(my_show)

addMsgFunc()
```

Functions are first-class objects in Julia, which means that you can just pass them around by name.

Answer (score 0):

A "function pointer" is just a complicated C construction that is necessary because there is no other way of having a different name that you can use to refer to functions.

In Julia, you just literally create another name that refers to the same function object, as I had already done in my first answer, e.g.

```
hello() = "hi"
goodbye() = "ciao"

f = hello   # f is a "function pointer"
f()

f = goodbye
f()
```

You can easily put functions inside other data structures, e.g. a dictionary:

```
greeting = Dict("hello" => hello, "goodbye" => goodbye)

f = greeting["hello"]
f()
```